# firefox 6.0.1 defaults to 'mobile' view for most sites

Tags: browser, macos

for quite a few sites that I visit, firefox defaults to 'mobile' view as if I was using it from a smartphone or similar device.
This happens even after deleting the firefox.app package and all of the preferences I can find and reinstalling.
Is this normal, quirky behavior or does it point to malicious activity?
I am using OS X 10.5.x

Comment: This really is not related to security in any way, is it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question: Based on the information you provided I do not think there is any reason to suggest malware is involved.

To help you troubleshoot this: It does sound like you user agent string was modified for some reason. You can easily view the string from this site: http://whatsmyuseragent.com

Comment: the user agent string looks correct AFAIK: Mozilla/5.0
Macintosh
Intel
Mac
OS
X
10.5
rv
6.0.1
Gecko/20100101
Firefox/6.0.1  ----Does that look normal? i will accept your answer, but I want to leave it open for a bit to see if there is any more input